# Scrapy login works for certain website but does not work for other websites

Tags: python, scrapy

I can use below code to login to Github. But when I try the same code to other websites, it still remains at the login page, it does not login. Did I miss anything?

- Github

```
class GithubSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/login'] 

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata=
                                         {
                                             'csrf_token': token,
                                             'login': '*******',
                                             'password': '*******'
                                         },
                                         callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print('yes')
```

- Airline website

```
class AirlineSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['hawaiianairlines.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.hawaiianairlines.com/my-account/login/']

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata=
                                         {
                                             'csrf_token': token,
                                             'UserName': '*********',
                                             'Password': '*********'
                                         },
                                         callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print('yes')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be more specific. What does "does not work" mean? Any errors? Does that airlines website even have with the fields you expect? You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Some websites have javascript that is required in order to be executed, captchas that may only be served to clients that look like a bot, or other ways to prevent automatic login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the website you provided, you can find the form field here:

```
<form id="login" ng-submit="login.$valid && submitLogin()" onsubmit="return false" novalidate="" name="login" method="post">
```

This, in particular the `onsubmit="return false"` part, tells you that this form will never be submitted by the browser through the usual method to the 'href' target and (unless you tested the form without javascript enabled and it works) that this site will probably only work in javascript-enabled browsers.

To then find out how the form is actually submitted, through XHR, you'd need to find and take apart the `submitLogin()` function here in the site's javascript code and emulate it in your code.

Another option is to use a javascript engine with scrapy, which can handle the scripts for you, but has the disadvantage of being more ressource intensive and possibly hard to set up.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation! Yes I saw the Hawaiian website has that onsubmit="return false", but when I tried the website ("https://steamcommunity.com/login") that I'm interested in scraping, it doesn't have that onsubmit="return false". In the steam website, when I use the same code I was trying with GitHub, it does not work either. Could you help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: @abab, the javascript that does the "return false" doesn't have to be written _inline_, as it was in this instance. It's just as easily possible to hide the JS in a script-file, which then "attaches" to the form element on execution (e.g. `document.getElementById("myformid");`) and can do the same. As a rule of thumb, try the website with javascript disabled, if it works you're good, else you'll need to figure out why it doesn't, and look through the scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried run the code with javascript disabled, but it does not work either. My friend had used the Beautiful soup to script the exactly same website (steam), and it works fine, so I think it shouldn't be that complicated... I'm very new to the python scrapy, and not sure how I can figure out what to cause the issue for not working.